Is carrying a (lock) knife in the UK already considered as having the intention to commit a criminal offence?
Is simply carrying a (lock) knife (for professional reasons) in the UK already considered as having the intention to commit a criminal offence?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Lock Knives are not Foldable Pocket Knives
R v Deegan [1998] 2 Cr. App. R. 121 CA reads:

We furthermore take the view that to construe the phrase "folding pocketknife" in any other way than that which it was construed by the Divisional Court would be impermissible. Obviously there is force in the view that Parliament really should not have brought what used to be called pen knives which have devices for locking the blades for reasons of safety, within the penal provisions of the Statute. A carrier of such should, it can be said, not have been required by Parliament to provide a "good reason" for having the article with him. However, it seems to us that "folding" in its ordinary meaning, means "foldable" at all times without the intervention of some further process, namely the pressing of a button or release of a catch, and that if any form of "lock knives" are to be brought outside the legislation, that will need clearer definition. The final point to make will be said to be a slightly unfair one in the light of the difficulties in finding the time to put forward legislation.
But the decision of the Divisional Court was in July 1992. There does not appear to have been any move to amend the legislation. That may demonstrate either that there is no great pressure to amend the legislation and not the perceived unfairness on the part of carriers of pocketknives whose blades can be locked as above described. Alternatively, it may demonstrate that there are real difficulties in defining precisely that form of pocketknife with a locking device which should fall outside the section, and, that the better view is, that albeit the present legislation will place an onus on some persons to provide a reason for carrying a knife which at first sight may seem unreasonable, that is an inconvenience which the few should suffer for the benefit of the community as a whole.
Accordingly we would dismiss the appeal. Application for leave to appeal to the House of Lords refused, but point of general public importance certified as follows:
'That the article 'a folding pocket knife' as mentioned in section 139(2) Criminal Justice Act 1988 as being an exemption subject to subsection (3) to the offence made by section 139(1) means a knife that has a blade that folds, whether or not it (the blade) is capable of being opened and locked into an open position and equally capable of being folded once the mechanism had been operated to unlock the blade.'

That means to claim the exception, the pocket knife needs to be able to be folded. Probably it might mean that you might need to be able to overcome the lock in some way, even if engaged, but the wording of the court is convoluted.

No, because there is an allowance for work use:

It is a defence for a person charged with an offence under section 139 of the Criminal Justice Act 1988 to prove that he or she had good reason or lawful authority for having the article in a public place. There are also specific defences in respect of:

use at work



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
